# Max number of masters a redis cluster can support

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, redis-cluster, ioredis

I went through the redis cluster documentation and there it is written that there are 16384 slots in a redis cluster (cluster mode enabled). Does this mean that there can be a maximum of only 16384 master nodes in a cluster?

If yes, then how do we scale beyond 16384 master nodes?

If no, then how will it work since at least one pair of two master will be assigned the same hash slot?

Comment: Just curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

The key space is split into 16384 slots, effectively setting an **upper limit for the cluster size of 16384 master nodes** (however the suggested max size of nodes is in the order of ~ 1000 nodes).

For more information Refer this: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec

Hope this helps :)